# Use DbModelBuilder in .NET Core to use specify naming conventions

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dbcontext

In .NET I would normally be able to specify naming conventions on all columns and tables in the following way

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Properties()
        .Where(p => p.Name == p.DeclaringType.Name + "_ID")
        .Configure(p => p.IsKey());

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

But in .NET Core I can't find a way of doing this. When I override `OnModelCreating()` in the XYZContext that inherits from DbContext in .NET core, I only have a [ModelBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelbuilder)

Is there a way of doing the above in .NET core or do I have to specify each column manually?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811336/onmodelcreating-undefined-in-entity-framework-7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ModelBuilder` allows similar functionality:

```
var keyProperties = modelBuilder
    .Model
    .GetEntityTypes()
    .SelectMany(e => e.GetProperties())
    .Where(p => p.Name == p.DeclaringEntityType.ClrType.Name + "_ID")
    .ToList();

foreach (var p in keyProperties)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity(p.DeclaringEntityType.Name)
        .HasKey(p.Name);
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you! I was just about to post the answer as I worked it out from another thread

Answer (score 1):

It's built into ModelBuilder.

Call `modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()` to get the types

To change the table name then use the following line of code

```
entityType.Relational().TableName = ConvertToUpperCaseUnderscore(entityType.ClrType.Name);
```

To map the properties to a columns using the same convention, call `entityType.GetProperties()` to get the list of properties, and map the column name.

So, overall usage is

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        if (entityType.ClrType == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        // Set the table name mapping for the class
        entityType.Relational().TableName = ConvertToUpperCaseUnderscore(entityType.ClrType.Name);

        var props = entityType.GetProperties().ToList();

        foreach (var p in props)
        {
            // Set the column name mapping for the class
            p.Relational().ColumnName = ConvertToUpperCaseUnderscore(p.Name);
        }
    }

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```